# sklearn.datasets fetch_olivetti_faces IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: sockets, scikit-learn, dataset, ssl-certificate, errno

I try to use fetch_olivetti_faces datasets from sklearn, but for some reasons I can't solve this IOError if you can help me:

Here is the code I run:

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces()
```

This is the IOError I get:

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Here is the all error I get:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/olivetti_faces.py", line 120, in fetch_olivetti_faces
mat_path = _fetch_remote(FACES, dirname=data_home)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 874, in _fetch_remote
urlretrieve(remote.url, file_path)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
h.endheaders(data)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
self.send(msg)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 844, in send
self.connect()

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1263, in connect
server_hostname=server_hostname)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 363, in wrap_socket
_context=self)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 611, in __init__
self.do_handshake()

File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 840, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()

IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Comment: Found a solution by dowloading directly the data from the https webpage instead of http webpage

Answer (score 6):

You can solve the problem just by importing the ssl package and executing the following command through the lines:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Note that this *disables certificate validation*, effectively turning off SSL. This solution is fine in a development environment, but sorting out your certificates is imperative before using this anywhere public-facing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem using custom SSL certificate inside your network.
In this case you should add your certificate into trusted certificate list.

Alternative way is downloading the file manually. And changing the `sklearn/datasets/olivetti_faces.py` file:

```
FACES = RemoteFileMetadata(
    filename='olivettifaces.mat',
    url='https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/5976027',
    checksum=('b612fb967f2dc77c9c62d3e1266e0c73'
              'd5fca46a4b8906c18e454d41af987794'))
```

You can copy the file manually into your local webserver and change this parameter into: `http://yourhost/yourfile.tar.gz`

This worked for me after annoying processes.