# How to download sklearn datasets in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am starting out with Pycharm, but when I am trying to fetch the sklearn datasets using pycharm I am receiving an Exception for unable to fetch data. I recently downloaded Pycharm with most Libraries at their latest versions.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', as_frame=False)
X, y=mnist.data, mnist.target
```

Received the following error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate 
verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1002)>
```

Comment: Hope this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734530/sklearn-datasets-fetch-olivetti-faces-ioerror-errno-socket-error-ssl-certif) help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn.datasets fetch\_olivetti\_faces IOError: \[Errno socket error\] \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:661)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47734530/sklearn-datasets-fetch-olivetti-faces-ioerror-errno-socket-error-ssl-certif)